# How can I get PhpStorm to comment a line at the beginning of the text and not line?

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm

In PhpStorm when you press "Cmd + /" it will comment the line beginning with // like so...

```
//      $numbers = explode(',', $numbers);
```

What I'd like it to do is to put the // at the beginning of the text so as to keep my indented code more readable like this...

```
        //$numbers = explode(',', $numbers);
```

Does anyone know a way to do this in PhpStorm?

Comment: A habit I have is selecting multiple lines. Even if I only want to comment one line I drag to the end of the previous line then ctrl + Shift + / for block comment (on my box).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I may have found what you want. File > Settings > Editor > Code Style > PHP (or whatever) > Other uncheck the 'Line comment at first column' box under Code Commenting. I am using v8.0.2 so might be slightly different for other versions. Let me know if that is what you were looking for.

Comment: Ah you found it! Thank you!

Comment: v2020: ...> PHP (or whatever) > Code Generation > Comment Code. Also don't forget to switch `Scheme` to *IDE* from *Project* if you want the setting to be permanent and not just for one project.

Answer (score 1):

Update 02/2024 - PhpStorm 2023.3.3

File > Settings > Editor > Code Style > {Language} > Code Generation > Line comment at first column